# Test Marionette vent.on Listener

Tags: backbone.js, jasmine, marionette

I have a `Layout` that has a `vent.on` call in it that gets setup on model initiation.

```
initialize: () ->
  App.vent.on("deciseconds:updated", this.updateDVR)

 updateDVR: () ->
  console.log 'this updateDVR is called'
```

I want to make sure `this.updateDVR` is hooked up correctly in my app.  In my tests I have this:

```
beforeEach ->
  this.showDvr = new Arc.DvrApp.Show.DvrView()
  spyOn(this.showDvr, 'updateDVR')

it "calls updateDvr when new data comes in", ->
  Arc.vent.trigger("deciseconds:updated")
  expect(this.showDvr.updateDVR).toHaveBeenCalled()
```

This spec is failing, but when I check my log I am seeing `this updateDVR is called`, the line I was logging in the `updateDVR` function.  So I know the function is being called.

It I directly call `updateDVR`, the spec passes:

```
it "calls updateDvr when new data comes in", ->
  this.showDVR.updateDVR()
  expect(this.showDvr.updateDVR).toHaveBeenCalled()
```

I thought the `vent` might be treated as an asynchronous function, so I tried waiting a few seconds before the `expect` clause to see if that would work, but it didn't:

```
it "calls updateDvr when new data comes in", ->
  Arc.vent.trigger("deciseconds:updated")
  setTimeout(myCheck, 3000)

myCheck = () ->
  expect(this.showDvr.updateDVR).toHaveBeenCalled()
```

Comment: I think a Jasmine spy replaces the original function, doesn't it? (You have to call .andCallThrough() to have it call the original function.) So I'm not sure how your original updateDVR() is being called to create that log message within this test. Could another test be calling updateDVR() & logging that message when your spy is not in place?

Comment: @MikeStapp Good call on the spy taking over control of the function.  Let me look into if another spec was giving us a false positive

Comment: @MikeStapp You are one to something. If I call `Arc.vent.trigger` I am getting the defualt method behavior, but if I call `this.showDvr.updateDVR` I am getting nothing back (expected, because the spy doesn't pass through to the regular function). For some reason, the `spy` isn't being placed on the object.  It seems to only have context in the testing frame

Comment: Is `Arc.vent` an alias to `App.vent`?

Comment: @pdoherty926 Yea. Specifically, we call our "app" Arc, so that is the window variable that holds all of the Marionette/Backbone info

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The call to `App.vent.on` in your `initialize` function passes a **reference** to the view instance's `this.updateDVR` function -- and that happens right before you `spyOn(this.showDvr, ...)` in the test's `beforeEach`. So when you trigger the event, the trigger calls that retained reference to the actual `updateDVR` function, not the spy.

You should be able to fix it by passing a callback function to the `App.vent.on` call, like so (sorry for the javascript, I'm not a coffeescripter!):

```
initialize: function () {
    var that = this;
    // hold onto the callback so we can unregister it in App.vent.off, too 
    this.onUpdateCb = function() { that.updateDVR() };
    App.vent.on("deciseconds:updated", this.onUpdateCb );

    // if this is a view, stop listening for App.vent when the view closes
    this.listenTo(this, 'close', function() { App.vent.off("deciseconds:updated", this.onUpdateCb ) } );
}
```

That will make the event handler look up the symbol named "updateDVR" at the time the event is triggered, & it will call your spy as your test expects.

**Edit:** Updated to retain this.onUpdateCb so we can unregister the listener on close.

Comment: This is awesome! Is there any downside to having the callback function instead of just the reference that it previously was? Performance or some other weird caveat?

Comment: There's a very small performance hit for the extra function call, but that's about it. Shouldn't really be noticeable, since you're already incurring the small overhead of trigger(). Oh -- and there's a small bug in my code. :-)  Right now, you won't be able to App.vent.off() when you close your view, since I'm using an anonymous function. I'll edit my answer to fix it up.

Comment: Very cool.  Thanks for the info.  Great catch on the `vent.off`.  I'll have to look into that and see where else I've done bad things like that

Comment: `listenTo` is a great replacement for all the `on`/`off` stuff: `this.listenTo(App.vent, "deciseconds:updated", this.onUpdateCb)` ... It can also bind the handler so you can avoid keeping track of `that`.